# Downloaded custom font not working; what am I doing wrong?

Tags: fonts, webfonts

This is my first time using a custom font on a site that I'm building. I chose this one:

https://fonts2u.com/final-fantasy-36-font-regular.font

I downloaded it and read some brief tutorials. They all say the same thing, to place the file with the downloaded font under css/fonts and then to include it in my stylesheet:

[image]

But, it's not transforming the text in the leftmenu. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know that my font call looks a great deal more complex than that.

```
/* BEGIN Light */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url("OpenSans/Light/OpenSans-Light.eot?v=1.1.0");
  src: url("OpenSans/Light/OpenSans-Light.eot?#iefix&v=1.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("OpenSans/Light/OpenSans-Light.woff2?v=1.1.0") format("woff2"), url("OpenSans/Light/OpenSans-Light.woff?v=1.1.0") format("woff"), url("OpenSans/Light/OpenSans-Light.ttf?v=1.1.0") format("truetype"), url("OpenSans/Light/OpenSans-Light.svg?v=1.1.0#Light") format("svg");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal; }
/* END Light */
/* BEGIN Light Italic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url("OpenSans/LightItalic/OpenSans-LightItalic.eot?v=1.1.0");
  src: url("OpenSans/LightItalic/OpenSans-LightItalic.eot?#iefix&v=1.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("OpenSans/LightItalic/OpenSans-LightItalic.woff2?v=1.1.0") format("woff2"), url("OpenSans/LightItalic/OpenSans-LightItalic.woff?v=1.1.0") format("woff"), url("OpenSans/LightItalic/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf?v=1.1.0") format("truetype"), url("OpenSans/LightItalic/OpenSans-LightItalic.svg?v=1.1.0#LightItalic") format("svg");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic; }
/* END Light Italic */
/* BEGIN Regular */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url("OpenSans/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.eot?v=1.1.0");
  src: url("OpenSans/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix&v=1.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("OpenSans/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.woff2?v=1.1.0") format("woff2"), url("OpenSans/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.woff?v=1.1.0") format("woff"), url("OpenSans/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.ttf?v=1.1.0") format("truetype"), url("OpenSans/Regular/OpenSans-Regular.svg?v=1.1.0#Regular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
/* END Regular */
```

The reason for using all of the different file formats is to allow different systems/browsers to use the format they "know". If you load only the `ttf` format, for example, an Apple/Safari setup might have no problems, but a Microsoft box running EI might not know what to do. Please, forgive me if I forget which font formats correspond to which browsers I think IE looks for `eot`. If it is *truly* important to have a brand font load, then I load them all.

I also use a general reset at the beginning of my `css`, including a general pointer towards the new font files:

```
*{
    /* typographic resets */
    font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:1.6em;
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

This, with careful path designations, should solve your problems. (Remember to clear your cache when testing.)

Note the "back-up" settings (`Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif`) which specify fonts which should load if our desired files should fail.

I believe that the information above is accepted as best-practice. Please SO, correct me if I am wrong.